# Usage of #selector directive in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delegates, selector

I have a protocol

```
protocol AnnotationTapDelegate: AnyObject {

    /* Delegate to identify the tap on Annotation view */
    func didTapAnnotation(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

and a class

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    func setTapDelegate(delegate: AnnotationTapDelegate!) {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: delegate, action: #selector(AnnotationTapDelegate.didTapAnnotation(_:)))  <== Error
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}
```

which gives me compile error saying "Argument of '#selector' refers to a method that is not exposed in Objective-C" and gives suggestion to "Add '@obj-c' to expose this to Objective-C". After adding '@obj-c' also, I get the same error and '@obj-c' is added again. Problem is not getting resolved.

I am working in Xcode 7.3.1.

Earlier I had

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: delegate, action: "didTapAnnotation:")
```

which was working fine. After updating my Xcode to 7.3.1, I am facing this problem.

How would I set my protocol's function as selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add @objc at the protocol level.

```
@objc
protocol AnnotationTapDelegate: AnyObject {

    /* Delegate to identify the tap on Annotation view */
    func didTapAnnotation(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: Actually '@obj-c' was added to the func. Adding it to protocol works.